# Dynamic Bytes Array Vyper

Tags: arrays, vyper

Can I make a dynamic bytes array in vyper?

Something like:

```py
checkData: DynArray[Bytes, 32]
```

For example, for create a function with the same function signature as a solidity func:

```js
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external {
```

Resulting signature:

```
checkUpkeep(bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Their technically isn't a dynamic bytes array in vyper, but if you want the match function signatures, you'd just do a `Bytes` array.

```py
def checkUpkeep(checkData: Bytes[32])
```